# Mock a method of already instantiated object

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-unittest, python-asyncio

I writing unit tests and for testing I want to mock a method of already existing object.
But looks like with asyncio corutines it is not so simple as it looks.
I tried to use MagickMock but it just doesn't work. There is no errors or exceptions, but with debugger I can see that f() is never being called.

My tests and object I want to patch look like this:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock

class Service(object):
   async def callback_handler(self, msg):
      pass

   async def handle(self, msg):
      await self.callback_handler(msg)

class TestCase(object):
    def setUp(self):
      self.service = Service()

    @patch('module.msg')  
    def test_my_case(self, msg_mock):
      f_was_called = False

      async def f():
        global f_was_called   
        f_was_called = True

      self.service.callback_handler = MagicMock(wraps=f) # here I try to mock
      await self.service.handle(msg_mock)
      assert f_was_called is True
```

How can I patch already instantiated object method with some custom one? Is there some issues with corutines?

Comment: Your question is a little short of providing a MCVE. I faced a couple of errors after just copy-pasting your code: 1. Usage of `await` inside a non-coroutine function `test_my_case` 2. Missing `module.py` that defines `msg()`. I tried to fix those errors to the best of my understanding but it would be better if you improve your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a context manager by replacing this line:

```
self.service.callback_handler = MagicMock(wraps=f) # here I try to mock
```

With this:

```
with mock.patch.object(self.service, 'callback_handler', side_effect=f) as mock_cb:
    ... # rest of code indented
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the problem trying to mock asyncio and want into a lot of troubles,

I ended using [pytest.asycio plugin](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio) .

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_some_asyncio_code():
    res = await library.do_something()
    assert b'expected result' == res
```